# How order of declaration of array can change the output?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was solving hackerrank problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/icecream-parlor/problem. If I declare `freq[]` first, all test cases passed, but if I declare `arr[]` first, two test cases failed. Can anyone explain why?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int freq[10004]; //This passes
int arr[10004];  //for all test cases
//int arr[10004]; but this fails
//int freq[10004]; for two test cases...why??

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        memset(freq, 0, sizeof(freq));
        int m, n, ansi, val;
        cin >> m >> n;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[j];
            freq[arr[j]]++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            freq[arr[j]]--;
            if (freq[m - arr[j]] > 0)
            {

                ansi = j;
                val = m - arr[j];
                cout << j + 1;
                break;
            }
            freq[arr[j]]++;
        }
        for (int j = ansi + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (val == arr[j])
            {
                cout << " " << j + 1 << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its most likely that one of your arrays (probably `arr`) is going out of bounds. I can't really see where it is going out of bounds - but there are lots of places it could be that don't have checks.  I would suggest to put bound check just before each access. For example before doing `cin >> arr[j];`  put `if ((j > 0) && (j < sizeof(arr)) { do stuff } else { print error}` (pseudo code). Then you can at least see where this is occurring...

Comment: `freq[m - arr[j]]` are you certain that `m - arr[j]` is `>=0` always? If not you have undefined behaviour and swapping two declarations can turn something that appears to work into something that does not appear to work, in any case it would need a fix

Comment: But why it works when order of declaration is changed?

Comment: @VishalKumar probably because (for one example) arr gets written to out of bounds (i.e. beyond its size) and possibly writes over freq. Or the other way around (freq gets written to below 0 (e.g. `freq[-1]` and overwrites arr... When you switch them freq is no longer after arr so writing to arr beyond the end does not over write freq.... but its overwriting something!  - its undefined behaviour meaning - its anyone's guess what happens!

Comment: @VishalKumar Your program has undefined behaviour, that means what it says. A program with a bug can still work. Then some trivial change which shouldn't change anything means it stops working. There's nothing in C++ that says bugs **must** cause a program to fail.

Comment: replace `int freq[10004];` with `std::array<int, 10004> freq;` and do the same with `arr`. Then replace all uses of the `[]` operator with calls to `std::array::at`. This will make the code run slower, but the program with throw an exception when an out-of-bounds access is made. A debugger usually halts and allows you to take control of the program when an uncaught exception occurs so you can inspect the backtrace to see what and where things when wrong.

Comment: By the way, watch out for `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)) and `using namespace std;` ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))  as both can cause problems. Putting the two together makes the potential for problems much, much worse. When you have a mystery bug, these are two of the first things that should be removed from the code to eliminate them as possible sources of error.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for helping. I just learned something new. My code now works . I added a condition in if statement

      if(freq[m-arr[j]]>0 && m>arr[j])

Comment: If you can explain HOW that solves the problem, you should post an answer to the question. No point leaving it dangling.

Comment: the reason it "worked" is probably because accessing `arr` with a negative index you end up in the upper end of `freq` (important: there is no rule that would explain this, thats just what the compiler does to your code because you are doing something wrong), while in the other case a negative index into `arr` ends up in memory not owned by your program

Comment: I am not able to ask more questions . It says to edit this question according to the complaints. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the comments. Here is a simple example:

```
// Two arrays of size 10
int arr[10];
int freq[10];

// Write to freq filling it with 1's
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
{
    freq[i] = 1;
}

// Write to arr filling it with 2'.... 
// but by mistake go wrote 11 times when the arr is only 10 long.
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++);
{
    arr[i] = 2;
}
```

Where did `arr[10] = 2` get written to?

It could be that freq is next in memory and so the first element of freq now contains a 1.

Or it could be that somthing else is after arr - we don't know, its up to the compiler/linker/os as to what that memory contains. This is why its called undefined behaviour - its out of your control.

E.g. after the first loop:

```
         |arr----------------|freq---------------
Memory:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Written:                      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Then after the second loop:

```
         |arr----------------|freq---------------
Memory:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Written:  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
                              ^
                        Over written the array
```

You could catch your issue with some bound checks:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++);
{
    if (i >= 0 && i < sizeof(arr))
    {
        arr[i] = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Arr out of bounds at: " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My code now works . I added a condition in if statement

      if(freq[m-arr[j]]>0 && m>arr[j]){
                
          }

Comment: @VishalKumar thats the wrong way around, once you accessed `freq[m-arr[j]]` its too late. Write `if(m>arr[j] && freq[m-arr[j]]>0){ }` instead

Comment: Okay. Thank you.